# React Native - Execute code in background on specific battery percentage

Tags: react-native, background-process, batterylevel

I have a react native application where the user can choose any battery level from 15 to 100. When his battery reaches the chosen value, javascript code should be executed.

Is there a way to do this when the app is in the background? I am aware I can have long running tasks, which will be displayed as a notification to the user and I can have my code logic there.

Are there any alternatives that do not include long running tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this problem to register a BroadcastReceiver in android, which will be executed every time when the battery percentage changes. It works in background and if the battery reaches a certain threshhold, a headless task can be executed which will run javascript code.